# sum until reach a value postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

I need to create a query to sum values until I reach a certain amount.

```
select client_id, dt, SUM(value)
from my_table
group by 1, 2;
```

My table is something like this:

```
client_id |    dt      |  value
----------+------------+-------
    23    | 2023-01-01 |   200
    23    | 2023-01-02 |   800
    23    | 2023-01-03 |   500
```

My expected result is **client_id: 23** | **sum: 2023-01-02**, that is the day that the sum reached 1000 (200 + 800).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine a windowed `sum()` with `distinct on` as follows:

```
with running as (
  select client_id, dt, 
         sum(value) over (partition by client_id 
                              order by dt) as run_total
    from my_table
)
select distinct on (client_id) client_id, dt, run_total
  from running
 where run_total >= 1000
 order by client_id, dt;
```

[Working example.](https://dbfiddle.uk/t5iALHuc)

Comment: Thanks Mike, this query solved my problem!